# Does the time complexity of these two sample code differs, How?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Given some problems in a recruitment process, a problem was to find the first non-repeating character from a given string in Java.
Below are the two sample codes out of which the first one was able to pass all the test cases but the second failed in few of the test cases due to time complexity. As I'm new to algorithm and complexity analysis, can someone help me out to understand whether the time complexity of these two codes differs and how ?

**Sample Code 1 :**

```
public static char firstNonRepeatingCharater(String s) {
    for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i))) {
            return s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return '_';
}
```

**Sample Code 2 :**

```
public static char firstNonRepeatingCharater(String s) {
    for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=s.length()-1;j>=0; j--) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count == 1) {
            return s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return '_';
}
```

Comment: In the first sample code, lastIndexOf method is used. So, to get the last index it might also be using loop. If not how it is able to find it

Comment: @Guy the first one has the loops as well since both `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` loop.

Comment: Both are O(n^2*m), actually, indexOf also has O(n*m) complexity where n is the length of the text and m is a length of the pattern, here m is 1 hence overall complexity is O(n^2) in both cases.

Comment: The second snippet can (and should) `break` after the second `count++`, looking for further matches is not needed.

Comment: @Raghu Chahar, but the second one failed in time complexity for few test cases

Comment: @RamPratapRanjan Look at your code and try some more optimizations, you can limit the internal loop to ```j>i``` instead of ```j>=0```, also stop calling ```s.length()``` every time you loop, you should store it in a variable instead there might be some more optimization possible you should first try by yourself. One more thing that in code 1 ```s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))``` this thing makes no sense you can compare i directly with ```s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i))```.

Comment: @RamPratapRanjan  Regarding issues in code 2, you should either break the second loop after increasing count or move the return statement inside the if condition i.e return s.charAt(i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Computational Complexity

First off, from your question, I realize it will be good to explain quickly `time complexity` and `big oh notation`.

Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity):

> In computer science, the time complexity is the computational
>   complexity that describes the amount of time it takes to run an
>   algorithm. Time complexity is commonly estimated by counting the
>   number of elementary operations performed by the algorithm, supposing
>   that each elementary operation takes a fixed amount of time to
>   perform. [...]
>   Since an algorithm's running time may vary among different inputs of
>   the same size, one commonly considers the worst-case time complexity,
>   which is the maximum amount of time required for inputs of a given
>   size.

## Big O Notation

> Algorithmic complexities are classified according to the type of
>   function appearing in the big O notation. For example, an algorithm
>   with time complexity O(n). O(n) is a linear time
>   algorithm and an algorithm with time complexity O(n^alpha) for some constant
>   alpha >1 is a polynomial time algorithm.

## In Relation to the two code Samples

Have a look at the two code samples. Immediately we notice a few things.

1. The size of the code is much smaller in sample 1 . So possibly we may have less operations.
2. More importantly however, we notice a nested for-loop in the second sample. The first sample does not have one. This doesn't necessarily discount hidden costs of code within methods.

Lets' do a little experiment. Let's count the number of operations required in a averagely-bad situation (first non-repeating char is in the middle), when the `size of Z is  = 1, 10, 100, and 1000`.

**Note: In this example/thought-experiment I will evaluate each line as an operation of cost 1. This is a gross simplification.** 
Forgive any omissions in counting the number of operations.

```
Algorithm 1: (size of s, lines executed)
-
1, 3
10, (2*5)+1 = 11
100, (2*50)+1 = 101
1000, (2* 500) + 1 = 1001
Total = (2* N/2 ) + 1
```

We see that the resulting number of executions is linearly related to the initial input size.

```
Algorithm 2: (N = size of s, lines executed)
-
1, 7
10, 2(5*5) + 2
100, 2(50*50) + 2
1000, 2(500*500) + 2
Total = ((N/2) *2 + 2*(N/2)*(N/2) + 2
```

In alogirthm 1 we see that the complexity is linearly related to the input size of s specifically `O(n)`.
In algorithm 2, we see that it is polynomial time, specifically `O(n^2)`. 
However, this becomes wrong once we take into consideration the real cost of `indexOf`and `lastIndexOf`.

### Adding the cost of indexOf and LastIndexOf

```
Let n=Size of the String S
```

Algorithm 1: (Roughly Estimated # of Operations)

```
 for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i++) // -  N/2
     if(s.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i))) {  // ~ worst case =  (N/2 + N/2) * N/2
     return s.charAt(i); // 1 operation

     Total = N/2 + (N/2 + N/2)*N/2 +1 
    = N^2/2 + N/2  + 1
```

Algorithm 2: (Roughly Estimated # of Operations)

```
    for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i++) { // - executed N/2 times
        int count = 0;               // - executed N/2 times
        for(int j=s.length()-1;j>=0; j--) {  // Executed (n/2 * n/2 )
            if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {  // Executed (n/2 * n/2 ) 
                count++;                      // Executed 1 time 
            }
        }
        if(count == 1) {                      //Evaluated N/2 times
            return s.charAt(i);               // Executed 1 time
        }
    }
    return '_';

Total = N/2 + N/2 + 2(N/2*N/2) + 1
= N^2/2 + N + 1
```

**Notes:** I did quite a few simplifications. I also assumed that the non-repeating character would be located in the center (n/2) of the String (Character Array). 
The main point to take is that the estimated # of executed operations increases as the size increases. The above example is aimed to prove the point. Not be 100% accurate.

Additionally, the whole result/argument as pointed out in the comments, is how we consider the indexOf and lastIndexof. Do we consider them as single operations? Or do we consider them as N/2 operations? It also depends on the implementation of indexOf and lastIndexOf. If these are searching through the array, they are hiding `for loops` inside. In the case that they do (last example), the cost of both algorithms becomes much more similar.

```
Algo1: N^2/4 + N/2  + 1
VS
Algo2: N^2/2 + N + 1
```

Comment: @Mentos did you consider the complexity of ```indexOf``` and ```lastIndexOf``` they too have at least O(n) complexity.

Comment: @Raghu Chahar As I said I simplified. My main point was the nested for loop that increased complexity to N^2 . I considered the nested for loop to be much worse. However, it is true that the indexOf and lastIndexOf themselves also have a cost of iterating through characters O(N).

Comment: `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` are both linear. The first snippet is also O(n^2)

Comment: Did you consider nested for loop much worse in this specific case or generally? Am I missing out on something? Still, worst case complexity seems O(n^2) to me.

Comment: Do the experiment. I'm updating the rough results to account for the addition of `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. Watch how the # of operations increases as the size of the input set increases. Nested for loops are a bad sign.

Comment: It seems that you did something wrong in Algorithm 1: i.e you didn't consider the complexity of indexOf and lasIndexOf, this would make it more worse i.e outerloop complexity(n) * ( innerindexOf complexity(n) + lastIndexOf complexity(n) + two charAt i.e O(2)) this would make it O(n*(n+n+2))

Comment: @Menios In case 1 You need to multiply n/2 and n/2 to calculate correct complexity.

Comment: @Raghu Chahar you are right. It is also a nester-for-lop. Just hidden inside the idexOf implementation. Thanks! I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Menios, glad you figure it out.

Comment: @Raghu Chahar Glad you kept me on my toes and helped me fix this into a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second snippet is less efficient.

In the second snippet, you count the number of occurrences of each character, and you return the first character having a single occurrence. This is less efficient than calling `s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))` and `s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(i))`, which only searches for two occurrences.

You can easily improve the second snippet to behave the same as the first (i.e. break out of the inner loop once you find an occurrence of `s.charAt(i)` at an index != `i`).

That said, both snippets have the same asymptotic running time, since both  `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` can require linear time in the worst case, which is the same as the inner loop of the first snippet.

On the other hand, for some inputs the first snippet is much faster than the second. If, for example, all the characters of the String are equal, the first snippet will take linear time (since both `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` will have to examine just one character of the String each time they are called), but the second snippet will take quadratic time.

Of course, a more efficient implementation than either the first or second snippets would be to use a `HashSet` in order to keep track of the characters that already appeared. This can be done in a single iteration of the `String`, which will require linear time.

Comment: The second paragraph isn't true. `indexOf` returns the first occurence. For a string `abbaba` and `i=5` it will return `0`.

Comment: @Amongalen and luk2302 yes, you are right. I missed that. Thanks. Corrected now.